# why does this vuelidate function not work within setup, but only outside, within methods?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuelidate

I'm using vuelidate with the composition API and I don't understand why the `v$.validate()` works correctly when I put within `methods`, after `setup`, but not within `setup`.

So this works:

```js
setup() {
  // inspired from 
  // https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/#alternative-syntax-composition-api
  const state = reactive ({
    // the values of the form that need to pass validation, like:
    name: ''
  })

  const rules = computed (() => {
    return {
      // the validation rules
    }

  const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, state)

  return {
    state,
    v$
  }
},
methods: {
  async submitForm () {
    const result = await this.v$.$validate()
    // either result: validation succeeded : axios post call
    // or failure and error messages show up.
  }
}
```

but, this doesn't work:

```js
setup() {

  const state = reactive ({
    // the values of the form that need to pass validation, like:
    name: ''
  })

  const rules = computed (() => {
    return {
      // the validation rules
    }

  const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, state)

  const submitForm = async () {
    // **ERROR : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: v$.$validate is not a function**
    const result = await v$.$validate()
    // either result: validation succeeded : axios post call
    // or failure and error messages show up.
  }

  return {
    state,
    v$,
    submitForm
  }
}
```

That's a bit of a pain, because I use a composable for the axios call where the `state` is an argument. Would be easier to keep the entire code in one place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Composition API](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/advanced_usage.html#composition-api)

> `useVuelidate` returns a `computed`, so you need to use `.value` when accessing any of it's properties, like `$error`, `$validate` inside the `setup` function.

> In the template it is unwrapped for you.